# How to test if methods work TOGETHER well?

Tags: php, unit-testing

class to test:

```
class TestMe
{
    public function add ($a, $b)
    {
        return $a + $b;
    }

    public function mul ($a, $b)
    {
        return $a * $b;
    }

    public function sumAddMul ($a, b)
    {
        $i = $this->add ($a, $b);
        $j = $this->mul ($a, $b);
        return $i + $j;
    }
}
```

testclass:

```
public function testAdd()
{
    $sut = new TestMe();
    $this->assertEquals (9, $sut->add(4,5));
}

public function testAdd()
{
    $sut = new TestMe();
    $this->assertEquals (8, $sut->mul(4,2));
}

public function testSumAndMul()
{
    ?
}
```

so, how to test `sumAndMul()`? Of course, I can write:

```
public function testSumAndMul()
{
    $this->assertEquals (3, $this->sut->sumAndMul(1,1));
}
```

the problem is its like testing something again what has been tested already. Its rather testing something that cooperating each other.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing a real life example would make more sense I'm guessing. But the way you've suggested is probably the best when you have more complex functions and more complex tests. Of course in the given instance you can just do the following to kill three birds with one stone:

```
public function testSumAndMul()
{
    $sum       = $sut->add(1, 1);
    $mul       = $sut->mul(1, 1);
    $sumAndMul = $sut->sumAndMul(1, 1);

    $this->assertEquals(2, $sum);
    $this->assertEquals(1, $mul);
    $this->assertEquals(3, $sumAndMul);
}
```

Unit testing is about testing the possible smallest units. When you start testing bigger chunks you start deviating from the rule. Keeping each test as independent as possible would be without a doubt the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry so much that `sumAndMul()` internally calls other methods here, given that there's no internal logic which changes its behaviour based in inputs (if that makes sense).

Just test that it returns a predictable value: eg: if you pass it `17` and `19` you get `359` back out.

Ask yourself if you really *care* how the method under test arrives at its result, or whether it's that it *does* arrive at its result (and what the result is) that matters.

I don't think it matters to `sumAndMul()` that internally it calls `add()` and `mul()`? Obviously these are example methods, so seeing the *actual* situation might be helpful here?